# Change context property values and reload context in JSF+Spring Web Application

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I am building application using JSF 2.0 and Spring 3.1.
In spring application context file i am setting a property **XMLOutputFilePath**

```
Spring ApplicationContextFile : 

<bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="DetailsBean"
            class="sections.DetailsBeanFactory"
            factory-method="createInstance">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="${XMLOutputFilePath}" />
        </bean>
```

I am reading **XMLOutputFilePath** from config.property file when application deploys first time

JSF Bean code :

```
for (String filePath : _filePathList) {
                    System.setProperty("XMLOutputFilePath", filePath);
                    System.out.println("For file : " + filePath);
                    _context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");
//Some code here
                }
```

I wanted to do 2 things in my JSF Bean Class :

1. I have a list of file paths and I wanted to change **XMLOutputFilePath** value for each new file path with this new path. (can see in code..)
2. Reload the context using this new property value.

I am trying to do it in this way but its not working.It is not changing  *XMLOutputFilePath** value also not reading the context file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where in JSF lifecycle are you setting the property, and where in lifecycle are you reading the property?

Comment: @Abhay Post your code